# Trocar textos de do elemento título com html e javascript

Tags: javascript, html

Tenho o seguinte título:

```
<h1>LANÇAMENTO: <span class="verde">PS5</span> E <span class="verde">XBOX SERIE S</span></h1>
```

No css mudo a cor da parte do span.
Tenho a função seguinte javascript para mudar o texto:

```js
function trocaTituto(){
  var titulo = $('.hero h1')
  var textos = ["CONFIRA NOSSAS NOVIDADES", "LANÇAMENTO: PS5 E XBOX SERIE S"]
  let position = 0
    setInterval(() => {
      //efeito de desaparecer
      $(titulo).fadeOut(function() {

      //função "callback" que mostra o próximo texto
      if (position >= textos.length) position = 0;
      $(titulo).text(textos[position++]).fadeIn();
      });

    }, 5000);
}
```

Como faço pra esta função colocar o texto verde quando voltar pra primeira parte?

Answer (score -3, accepted):

Seria próximo ao código abaixo?
voce pode adicionar a tag span junto ao texto, e trocar a função text() para html() pois assim passar a reconhecer texto junto html e fazer a troca das cores.

```js
function trocaTituto(){
  var titulo = $('.hero h1')
  var textos = ["CONFIRA NOSSAS NOVIDADES", `LANÇAMENTO: <span class='verde'>PS5</span> E <span class='verde'>XBOX SERIE S</span>`]
  
  let position = 0
    setInterval(() => {
      //efeito de desaparecer
      $(titulo).fadeOut(function() {

      //função "callback" que mostra o próximo texto
      if (position >= textos.length) position = 0;
      
      $(titulo).html(textos[position++]).fadeIn();
      }); 
     

    }, 1000);
}
```

```css
.verde{
 color: green; 
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="banner" id="banner"> 
 <section class="hero section"> 
  <h1> LANÇAMENTO: 
    <span id="verde1" class="verde">PS5</span> E <span id="verde2" class="verde">XBOX SERIES S</span> 
  </h1> <a href="#historia" class="btn-banner">Saiba mais</a> 
 </section> 
</div>
<button onclick='trocaTituto()'>trocar</button>
```

Comment: Tenho um h1 com algumas span dentro, para que algumas palavras fiquem com a cor branca e outras com a cor verde. Esta função fica alternando o texto desse h1, mas não consigo fazer ela alternar com as palavras de cores diferentes, ou fica tudo branco ou tudo verde.

Comment: pode compartilhar o código html? que ai eu consigo te ajudar melhor

Comment: É isso aqui
<div class="banner" id="banner">
        <section class="hero section">
            <h1>
                LANÇAMENTO: 
                <span id="verde1" class="verde">PS5</span>
                 E 
                <span id="verde2" class="verde">XBOX SERIES S</span>
            </h1>
            <a href="#historia" class="btn-banner">Saiba mais</a>   
        </section>
    </div>

Comment: no caso eu troco esse h1, consigo trocar o h1 completo, mas não os span que fazem algumas palavras ficarem de outras cores